# ASP.Net MVC AJAX Security?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i'm coding a website in MVC

so i am sending data with ajax, is this way safe?
can they manipulate my data?

i'm coding comments section so i am using the ajax to load comments page by page. Also i'm using ajax about this like and dislike situation

is there any problem about security? What should i do extra?

example codes ;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    YorumlariYenile("yorumlar", @(Model.KullaniciVeri.KULLANICI_ID), "PROFIL_YORUM", 1);
});

function YorumlariYenile(divId, HedefId, HedefMod, SayfaNo) {
    $("#" + divId).load("@(Url.Action("YorumCek", "Sayfa", null, Request.Url.Scheme))?HEDEF_ID=" + HedefId + "&HEDEF_MOD=" + HedefMod + "&SAYFA_NO=" + SayfaNo + "&DIV_ID=" + divId);
} 

function Yorumla(divId) {
    if ($("#" + divId).is(":visible")) {
        $("#" + divId).hide();
    } else {
        $("#" + divId).show();
    }
}

function YorumSil(YorumId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@(Url.Action("YorumSil", "Sayfa"))",
        data: { YORUM_ID: YorumId },
        success: function (data) {
            YorumlariYenile("yorumlar", @(Model.KullaniciVeri.KULLANICI_ID), "PROFIL_YORUM", 1);

            if (data != "Başarılı!") {
                $("#bilgiModal").modal("show");
                $("#bilgiLabel").text("Başarısız");
                $("#bilgiIcerik").html(data);
            }

        }

    });
}

function YorumYap(Yorum, HedefId, HedefMod, Spo) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@(Url.Action("YorumYap", "Sayfa"))",
        data: { txtYorum: Yorum, HEDEF_ID: HedefId, HEDEF_MOD: HedefMod, Spoiler: Spo },
        success: function (data) {
            YorumlariYenile("yorumlar", @(Model.KullaniciVeri.KULLANICI_ID), "PROFIL_YORUM", 1);

            if (data != "Başarılı!") {
                $("#bilgiModal").modal("show");
                $("#bilgiLabel").text("Başarısız");
                $("#bilgiIcerik").html(data);
            } 
        }

    });
}

function DegerlendirmeYap(HedefId, HedefMod, Begenme_Durumu) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@(Url.Action("DegerlendirmeYap", "Sayfa"))",
        data: { HEDEF_ID: HedefId, HEDEF_MOD: HedefMod, BEGENME_DURUMU: Begenme_Durumu },
        success: function (data) {
            YorumlariYenile("yorumlar", @(Model.KullaniciVeri.KULLANICI_ID), "PROFIL_YORUM", 1);

            if (data != "Başarılı!") {
                $("#bilgiModal").modal("show");
                $("#bilgiLabel").text("Başarısız");
                $("#bilgiIcerik").html(data);
            } 
        }

    });
}

function DegerlendirmeCek(spanId, HedefId, HedefMod, Begenme_Durumu) {        
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@(Url.Action("DegerlendirmeCek", "Sayfa"))",
        data: { HEDEF_ID: HedefId, HEDEF_MOD: HedefMod, BEGENME_DURUMU: Begenme_Durumu },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#" + spanId).text(data);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: It's javascript. It can be modified.

Comment: yeah, i know that so it will be a problem for me right?

Comment: It isn't entirely clear about what you're trying to achieve but it sounds like you may want to implement some server-side validation.

Comment: i am sending data to server-side by the ajax, so my worry is my site can be hacked with this way? i'm already added some validations for comments etc..

Comment: An Ajax request isn't different from any other HTTP request. You should use TLS (https) and always check permissions server-side as you can never rely on data from the client side.

Comment: It's not really any less secure than a regular request. The user can do whatever they like. They don't even need a browser to make requests to your site, just a tool like PostMan is sufficient. Your HTML GUI is for the user's convenience, it does not and cannot provide any actual security. Make sure your server validates all input (as it already should be doing anyway) before processing anything.